# Angular 9: LocalStorage is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, angular9

We are using angular 9 for a small school project. 
We want to use the local storage to store some user data, but on execution, we get a "localStorage undefined" error.

```
import {Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService, FacebookLoginProvider, SocialUser} from 'angularx-social-login';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

@Component({
selector: 'app-connexion',
templateUrl: './connexion.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./connexion.component.scss']
})

export class ConnexionComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private userService: UserService, private router: 
     Router) { }

ngOnInit() { }

signInWithFB(): void {
   this.authService.signIn(FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(user => {
       localStorage.setItem('usersocial', JSON.stringify(user));
    });
}
```

I don't see an error in the code, as we followed different documentations. We are testing on Chrome and checked the compatibility. 
Is there a way to exchange data between components either with localStorage or other method?

Comment: It is a runtime error right, not compile time? And you are not using SSR?

Comment: yes it is a runtime error. And no SSR

Comment: Is the error you are getting `localstorage undefined` as it is in your question or `localStorage undefined`. There is no `localstorage` in the code you have posted.

Comment: indeed it is "localStorage undefined", typo error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Angular 4. I am not sure if you're using Angular 4 as well, but try to include `"dom"` inside the `"lib"` property of `"compilerOptions"` in the `tsconfig.json` file.

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```